# JNI - Acces violation when writing to file from CPP

Tags: java, c++, windows, java-native-interface, cygwin

So here I am trying to write into a file from a C++ program that is called from Java using JNI.

The C++ contains the minimum, taken from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/).

```
#include "JNIHeader.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_myclass_writeSomeStuff(
    JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz) {
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("example.txt");
    myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    myfile.close();
    return 1;
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000180126ff7,     pid=3648, tid=13192
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_60-b27) (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.60-b23 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [cygwin1.dll+0xe6ff7]
```

When other non I/O methods are called, JNI calls works perfectly.

Compilation is done using G++ 4.9.3 with CYGWIN64 on a Windows 7 64 bits machine. Antivirus is turned off.

Right now, I am totally stucked (quite new to JNI) and any help is welcome !

Comment: You're not checking if the open call succeeds before trying to write to the file.